# Bind-mount volume of different type from guest to host

Tags: docker

having this bind-mount `-v /bar:/foo`, if on the Guest side I do `mount -t glusterfs x:y /foo`  then the new glusterfs mount "overrides" the older one to Host machine and the changes are not propagated to Host anymore, right?

Is there any way how to mount the Guest glusterfs `/foo` mount-point to Host machine? Because the classic bind-mount `-v /bar:/foo` doesn't work.

I cannot use docker volumes plugin. Because I'm on CoreOS and there everything runs in a docker container so I cannot install glusterfs client on CoreOS Host.